# interactively drawing rectangles on the image

Tags: python, opencv, pygame

Is it possible to interactively draw a rectangle on a image and store the coordinates in python? 
I have done this using OpenCV in c++ but after switching to python i cannot find a way to accomplish this.

I used pygame and the following script allows me to crop the image interactively. but instead of cropping i just want the rectangle coordinates. Is it possible to do this in python using opencv/pygame or any similar libraries?

```
import pygame, sys
from PIL import Image
pygame.init()

def displayImage( screen, px, topleft):
    screen.blit(px, px.get_rect())
    if topleft:
        pygame.draw.rect( screen, 0, pygame.Rect(topleft[0], topleft[1], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - topleft[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] - topleft[1]))
    pygame.display.flip()

def setup(path):
    px = pygame.image.load(path)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode( px.get_rect()[2:] )
    screen.blit(px, px.get_rect())
    pygame.display.flip()
    return screen, px

def mainLoop(screen, px):
    topleft = None
    bottomright = None
    runProgram = True
    while runProgram:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                runProgram = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if not topleft:
                    topleft = event.pos
                else:
                    bottomright = event.pos
                    runProgram = False
        displayImage(screen, px, topleft)
    return ( topleft + bottomright )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen, px = setup(sys.argv[1])
    left, upper, right, lower = mainLoop(screen, px)
    im = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
    im = im.crop(( left, upper, right, lower))
    im.save(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Saying `rectangle coordinates` you mean value from line `left, upper, right, lower = mainLoop(screen, px)` ?

Comment: yes. the values of the 4 corners instead of cropping the image

Comment: So you have it. `(left,upper)`, `(left,lower)`, `(right,upper)`, `(right,lower)`. What else do you need ?

Comment: damn, i was so screwed up I didnt think. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle coordinates of the image are:

```py
corner_pts = [(left,upper), (left,lower), (right,upper), (right,lower)]
```

However, if you're using pygame, I recommend using a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object and the virtual attributes `topleft`, `bottomleft´,` topright`,` bottomright`:

```py
def mainLoop(screen, px):
    pts = []
    runProgram = True
    while runProgram:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                runProgram = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                pts.append(event.pos)
                runProgram = len(pts) < 2
        displayImage(screen, px, topleft)

    x_pts, y_pts = list(zip(*pts)) 
    left, right, top, bottom, = min(x_pts), max(x_pts), min(y_pts), max(y_pts)
    return pygame.Rect(left, top, right-left, bottom-top)
```

```py
rect = mainLoop(screen, px)
corner_pts = [rect.topleft, rect.bottomleft, rect.topright, rect.bottomright]
```